# 404 Not Found When deploying laravel built with docker in a production environment

Tags: docker, nginx

404 error occur,  When accessing the specified URL.
I deployed laravel built with docker in a production environment.
I have confirmed that it works locally.I think that the specification of URL is strange. Locally, the URL uses localhost, and in the production environment, it uses the acquired domain.

.env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_KEY=<<APP_KEY>>
APP_URL=<<my_domain>>

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    container_name: php
    build: ./docker/php
    volumes:
      - ./server:/var/www

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 81:81
    volumes:
      - ./server:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db-host
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      TZ: 'Asia/Tokyo'
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/db/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
      - ./docker/db/sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - 3307:3307
```

default.conf

```
 server {
      listen 81;
        index index.php index.html;
        root /var/www/laravel/public;

        location / {
        root /var/www/laravel/public;
        index  index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;
        }
```

docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                         NAMES
A        nginx                "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   3 hours ago         Up About an hour    80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:81->81/tcp                    nginx
B        mysql:5.7            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago         Up 2 hours          3306/tcp, 33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3307/tcp   db-host
C        tsurikatsu_web_php   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   4 hours ago         Up 2 hours          9000/tcp                                      php
```

I expect laravel project is shown , but the actual output is 404 error

please help me.

Comment: I will assume that the APP_KEY and my_domain are just hidden for the purpose of the question. What is your nginx configurations, docker-compose.yml or whatever docker commands you are using? What image are you using? Will need a little more info about the actual setup you have going on there

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added information about this question.

Comment: Can you also provide the default.conf file? Of course hide the sensitive information before :) 
I am assuming you are using some sort of a server instance (DO, EC2 or whatnot) and managing the production deployment manually? By the looks of the docker-compose.yml it should be fine so it is possible that there are issues in the default.conf or maybe the server instance it self...

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I use 「vultr」 server which os is Ubuntu 18.10 x64. I added default.conf file.

Comment: Are you specifying the port 81 when visiting your site or forwarding the requests from 80 to 81 with your vultr server?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Is port 81 specified by nginx? and Is it nginx to transfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in your docker-compose.yml file, you are mapping your servers 81 port to the nginx container 81 port, which means that you have to visit your site by specifying port 81 unless you are forwarding traffic from port 80 to localhost:81.

If you are not using any proxy forwarding with your vultr server and your port 80 is not reserved by anything then I suggest you try either replacing the port mapping in nginx service with `80:81`

If that is not an option (something already uses port 80 on your server) then you should forward traffic from port 80 to port 81 whenever the specific hostname is being requested.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very polite commentary. After deleting all the images of docker once and setting the port of nginx of dokcer-compose.yml to 80:81 and executing docker-compose up -d "Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind : I got an error with "address already in use"

Comment: I believe that your vultr server is using the port 80. You need to either set up port forwarding with vultr or if vultr is not actually necessary in your set up you can simply stop the service so the port is no longer reserved

Comment: [1]I believe that your vultr server is using the port 80→yes
[2]I input 「sudo lsof -i:80」

result
nginx   6692     root    6u  IPv4 14717051      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   6692     root    7u  IPv6 14717052      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   6694 www-data    6u  IPv4 14717051      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   6694 www-data    7u  IPv6 14717052      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)

Can i kill these all process?

Comment: I am not familiar with vultr, but what you need to do is then in docker compose leave the port mapping as 81:81 and then use vultr as proxy and forward requests coming to your domain port 80 to localhost:81 (which in turn will forward it to your docker service)

Comment: Somehow, after killing all 80 port processes and executing docker-compose up -d, it became accessible in the specified domain. I could understand what Kārlis isbele says. When I have time I would like to do that too. I'm really thankful to you.